# Remove all two or more consecutive A's from a string using replaceAll()

Tags: java, replaceall

I want to remove all two or more consecutive `A`'s from a string.
i.e, if input is `AAAAAAABBABBCACBAAZASCAAA`
 output should be `BBABBCACBZASC`.

And what I tried is,

```
String k = "AAAAAAABBABBCACBAAZASCAAA";
System.out.println(k.replaceAll("(AA)+", "-").replaceAll("-A","").replaceAll("-", ""));
```

It works fine. But if the string contains `-` , it makes problem. How can i resolve it ?

Comment: Why not replace it with an empty string literal from the start?? It makes no sense to replace things to be removed with a placeholder....

Comment: That makes sense. Kind of. Input: "AAA" replacing with "(AA)+" will result in: "A", because the regex matches double A's.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`k.replaceAll("A{2,}", "-");`
is the pattern you want

Answer (score 1):

```
String k = "AAAAAAABBABBCACBAAZASCAAA";
System.out.println(k.replaceAll("(A{2,})", ""));
```

Answer (score 1):

You only need one replaceAll step, if you use the following:

```
String original = "AAAAAAABBABBCACBAAZASCAAA";
String replaced = original.replaceAll("A{2,}", "");
// assertEquals("BBABBCACBZASC",replaced);
```

Your regexp only matches an **even number** of *A*s, this is why you had to use the additional replaceAll steps to succeed. What you really want is, to replace *two or more consecutive* *A*s with "". In regexp, this requires the use of the correct quantifier, as explained in the [Quantifiers tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html). In your case: `A{2,}`.